# Jhipster and Oracle 11gr2?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, jhipster

Does anyone succeded to connect Jhipster to Oracle 11gr2 database ? 
I can't find where to insert the SID / instance 
I already installed Oracle JDBC for 11gr2. 
Still can't succeed to connect it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here how to do it bro:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev
  datasource:
    driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    dataSourceClassName: oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl(replace orcl by SID)
    username: rest_test
    password: rest_test
```